# Toggle Panels Failure Using Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, toggle

I am having issues with the Javascript that supports only 2 panel toggle. When adding a 3rd panel the Javascript fails to displays the correct panel. It could be a simple panel ID issue, but I don't seem to be able to set the ID for toggling with the radio buttons.

Here's the JSFiddle containing a 2 panel and a 3 panel example: http://jsfiddle.net/9z8735h3/5/

Here's the code:

```
<H4>2 Tab Version Work Great!</H4>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Languages">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#dotNet" data-toggle="tab">.NET</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#PHP" data-toggle="tab">PHP</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dotNet">
      <!--NAV TAB CONTENT SELECTION-->
      <form name="NetVersion">
        <input type="radio" id="Net40" name="thing" value="valuable" data-id="Net40" checked="checked" />
        <label for="Net40">4.0</label>
        |
        <input type="radio" id="Net56" name="thing" value="valuable" data-id="Net56" />
        <label for="Net56">5.6</label>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!--NAV TAB CONTENT SELECTION-->
      <div id="Net40View" class="col-lg-12 active">
        <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 4.0 Left</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 border-red">.NET 4.0 Right</div>
      </div>
      <div id="Net56View" class="col-lg-12 none">
        <div class="col-md-6 border-green active">.NET 5.6 Left</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 border-blue">.NET 5.6 Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="PHP">
      <h2>Some content here</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<hr />
<H4>But this 3 Tab Version Breakdows</H4>
<p>I would to be able to add 3 or more radio buttons and maintain the same experience as compared to the 2 tabs above.
</p>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Languages">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#dotNet" data-toggle="tab">.NET</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#PHP" data-toggle="tab">PHP</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dotNet">
      <!--NAV TAB CONTENT SELECTION-->
      <form name="NetVersion">
        <input type="radio" id="Net40" name="thing" value="valuable" data-id="Net40" checked="checked" />
        <label for="Net40">4.0</label>
        |
        <input type="radio" id="Net56" name="thing" value="valuable" data-id="Net56" />
        <label for="Net56">5.6</label>
        |
        <input type="radio" id="Net6" name="thing" value="valuable" data-id="Net6" />
        <label for="Net6">6.0</label>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <!--NAV TAB CONTENT SELECTION-->
      <div id="Net40View" class="col-lg-12 active">
        <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 4.0 Left</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 border-red">.NET 4.0 Right</div>
      </div>
      <div id="Net56View" class="col-lg-12 none">
        <div class="col-md-6 border-green active">.NET 5.6 Left</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 border-blue">.NET 5.6 Right</div>
      </div>
      <div id="Net6View" class="col-lg-12 none">
        <div class="col-md-6 border-green active">.NET 6.0 Left</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 6.0 Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="PHP">
      <h2>Some content here</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help with this issue as I am a newbie in Javascript.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of it is an element id issue. Though some would argue differently, [all element id names should be unique](http://devdocs.io/html/attributes#id), or the HTML is invalid. The current code contains multiple elements with the same id name. The second issue is, though the `.toggle()` call works when you have two elements, when you have three elements, you are going to end up toggling two of the elements to visible, when they are hidden, and one that is currently visible to hidden; hence, you need to be more specific when setting the elements as visible or hidden. Tweaked your current example to one that works with both 2 and 3 radio sets:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(function (){
    $('input[name=version-two-tab]:radio').change(function(event) {
        $('#Net40View-two-tab').toggle();
        $('#Net56View-two-tab').toggle();
    });
    $('input[name=version-three-tab]:radio').change(function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        if ($(this).data('id') === 'Net40-three-tab') {
            $('#Net40View-three-tab').show();
            $('#Net56View-three-tab').hide();
            $('#Net6View-three-tab').hide();
        }
        if ($(this).data('id') === 'Net56-three-tab') {
            $('#Net40View-three-tab').hide();
            $('#Net56View-three-tab').show();
            $('#Net6View-three-tab').hide();
        }
        if ($(this).data('id') === 'Net6-three-tab') {
            $('#Net40View-three-tab').hide();
            $('#Net56View-three-tab').hide();
            $('#Net6View-three-tab').show();
        }
    });
});
    </script>
    <style>
.none {
    display: none;
}
.border-red {
    border: solid 1px red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.border-blue {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.border-green {
    border: solid 1px green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
    </style>
    <title>Toggle Panels Failure Using Radio Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>

<h4>2 Radio Version</h4>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Languages-two-tab">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#dotNet-two-tab" data-toggle="tab">.NET</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#PHP-two-tab" data-toggle="tab">PHP</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dotNet-two-tab">

        <form>
            <input checked data-id="Net40-two-tab" id="Net40-two-tab" name="version-two-tab" type="radio">
            <label for="Net40-two-tab">4.0</label> |
            <input data-id="Net56-two-tab" id="Net56-two-tab" name="version-two-tab" type="radio">
            <label for="Net56-two-tab">5.6</label>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-lg-12 active" id="Net40View-two-tab">
            <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 4.0 Left</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 border-red">.NET 4.0 Right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 none" id="Net56View-two-tab">
            <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 5.6 Left</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 border-blue">.NET 5.6 Right</div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="PHP-two-tab">
        <h2>Some content here</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<hr>

<h4>3 Radio Version</h4>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Languages-three-tab">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#dotNet-three-tab" data-toggle="tab">.NET</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#PHP-three-tab" data-toggle="tab">PHP</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dotNet-three-tab">

        <form>
            <input checked data-id="Net40-three-tab" id="Net40-three-tab" name="version-three-tab" type="radio">
            <label for="Net40-three-tab">4.0</label> |
            <input data-id="Net56-three-tab" id="Net56-three-tab" name="version-three-tab" type="radio">
            <label for="Net56-three-tab">5.6</label> |
            <input data-id="Net6-three-tab" id="Net6-three-tab" name="version-three-tab" type="radio">
            <label for="Net6-three-tab">6.0</label>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-lg-12 active" id="Net40View-three-tab">
            <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 4.0 Left</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 border-red">.NET 4.0 Right</div>
        </div>
        <div id="Net56View-three-tab" class="col-lg-12 none">
            <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 5.6 Left</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 border-blue">.NET 5.6 Right</div>
        </div>
        <div id="Net6View-three-tab" class="col-lg-12 none">
            <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 6.0 Left</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 border-green">.NET 6.0 Right</div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="PHP-three-tab">
        <h2>Some content here</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm!  I appreciate your help.  Thank you, very much!

Comment: excellent! you are welcome. glad to hear that it helped out. :)